# How to exit a Kivy application using a button

Tags: python, kivy

I'm just learning Python and the Kivy framework. I can't seem to find any specific complete examples of being able to gracefully exit a Kivy app using code linked to a button.

I have found Kivy code snippets like this

```
Button:
    id:btnExit
    text:"Exit"
    on_press: app.Exit()
```

But not any matching code that implements the `app.Exit()` call. Everything I've tried stops code execution but doesn't clean up the program window.

I've read that Android and iOS style guides state that a program is not to programmatically exit and let the OS handle it but I am developing fullscreen borderless Desktop app and need a way to exit the program with a button press.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `App.get_running_app().stop()`.
For more details, read the [Kivy documentation article](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.close_settings) for the function.

Comment: That's one of the methods I tried but it doesn't clean up the window. The code stops executing but the window is not destroyed.

Comment: See this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/saWDLoYCSZ4

Comment: Thanks, your solution works when executing it from the python shell. I was having the same issue with the IDE not allowing the window to close.

Comment: To use above code in kv language file, you must import App like this: `#:import App kivy.app.App`

Answer (score 26):

Use [App.stop(*largs)](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html?highlight=stop#kivy.app.App.stop):

```
Button:
    id: btnExit
    text: "Exit"
    on_press: app.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `self.root_window.close()`.
There is bug in new android toolchain.

Comment: I prefer `quit() ` since it ends all pythonic codes no matter the framework. In kivy it'll be `on_press: quit() `

Comment: in kivy app quit() on_press : crash App (*in new android toolchain)

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
on_press : app.stop()
```

in Button's property in Kivy Layout File and it worked well for me.