# Exiting a Kivy application using a button - NameError

Tags: python, kivy

I want to be able to exit my python kivy application using a `Button` widget.

I've been looking at the answers in [How to exit a Kivy application using a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425831/how-to-exit-a-kivy-application-using-a-button) but I keep getting an error message.

I've tried to set the `on_press` argument to `ButtonApp.stop()`, as well as `ButtonApp().stop()`, and `ButtonApp.get_running_app().stop()`, but I keep getting a `NameError` error message. Why?

I'm using python 3.9.1, jupyter notebook 6.0.1.

Thanks!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv = '''
<NewButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100

    Button:
        text: "Exit"
        font_size: 20     
        pos: 50, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 50, 25  
        on_press: ButtonApp.stop()
    
'''

class NewButton(FloatLayout):
    def callback1(self):  
        pass
            
class ButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return NewButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ButtonApp().run()
    
# ERROR MESSAGE 
NameError: name 'ButtonApp' is not defined
```

Comment: Replace the on_press: ButtonApp.stop() to on_press: app.stop()

Comment: @NorbertTiborcz, thanks for your comment. I tried on_press: app.stop(), but it seems to cause python to crash and the kivy output says 'Leaving application in progress'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `on_press: ButtonApp.stop()` with `on_press: app.stop()` or

```
#:import App kivy.app.App
on_press: App.get_running_app().stop()
```

Result will be the same.